# Flask app is not running when pyinstaller is used with --noconsole

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I have created a basic hello world application in flask. Then I did 
`pyinstaller --noconsole main.py`. I have got main.exe file in /dist directory.
When I tried to run it, I am getting an alert of error showing Failed to execute script main

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Comment: I have to hide the console.

Comment: Try to see if there is more detailed error message in the console first. Then you can hide it once this whole thing works.

Comment: no error message in console. It works perfectly in console

Comment: In console or with console? Does it work like that `pyinstaller main.py` ?

Comment: I could run ```python main.py``` and could run the app in localhost. Then I did ```pyinstaller main.py``` which worked fine. The problem is that it have a terminal. I don't need a terminal. So I did ```pyinstaller --noconsole main.py```.It is not working leaving an error alert as "Failed to execute script main"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196720/discussion-between-aneesh-jose-and-andrey).

Comment: Then I am out of guesses to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect stdout, either no nothing `sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')` or to file `sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')` if you still want to be able to view its output at some stage

You can add the desired function to the top of your flask script

Comment: Wow, first of all thank you. This seems to be an issue I couldn't wrap my mind around and many people seem to face with pyinstaller.